# When to use fixed value protobuf type? Or under what scenarios?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to transfer a serialized protobuf message over TCP and I've tried to use the first field to indicate the total length of the serialized message.

I know that the `int32` will change the length after encoding. So, maybe a `fixed32` is a good choice.

But at last of the Encoding chapter, I found that I can't depend on it even if I use a fixed32 with field_num #1. Because [Field Order](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#order) said that the order may change.

My question is when do I use fixed value types? Are there any example scenarios?

Comment: I think the documentation explains this well enough: if the length of the serialized value is non-constant, then the length must be embedded in the serialized message somehow. This causes overhead for specific values (larger than 2^28 as specified in the documentation). See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar

Comment: @Caramiriel Thanks!  Got it. You can post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to add the total length to the message instead of just letting protobuf deserialise it for you? (I might be missing something.)

Comment: @Tanktalus I just want to using `recv` the specific length simply. I know I can split the protobuf message but I don't have any idea about how to do it easily.

Comment: You didn't specify your language, but when I've used protobufs, I found it best to just give the protobuf deserialiser the stream and let it just decode the data, and that way it would handle all the hard parts. (I just wish the implementations were implemented with async-await instead of being entirely sync. At least last time I looked.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "My question is when do I use fixed value types?"

When it comes to serializing values, there's always a tradeoff. If we look at the [Protobuf-documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar), we see we have a few options when it comes to 32-bit integers:

> **int32**: Uses variable-length encoding. Inefficient for encoding negative numbers – if your field is likely to have negative values, use sint32 instead.
>
> **uint32**: Uses variable-length encoding.
>
> **sint32**: Uses variable-length encoding. Signed int value. These more efficiently encode negative numbers than regular int32s.
>
> **fixed32**: Always four bytes. More efficient than uint32 if values are often greater than 2^28.
>
> **sfixed32**: Always four bytes.

`int32` is a variable-length data-type. Any information that is not specified in the type itself, needs to be expressed somehow. To deserialize a variable-length number, we need to know what the length is. That is contained in the serialized message as well, which requires additional storage space. The same goes for an optional negative sign. The resulting message may be smaller because of this, but may be larger as well.

Say we have a lot of integers between 0 and 255 to encode. It would be cheaper to send this information as a two bytes (one byte with that actual value, and one byte to indicate that we just have one byte), than to send a full 32-bit (4 bytes) integer *[fictional values, actual implementation may differ]*. On the other hand, if we want to serialize a large value, that can only fit in 4 bytes the result may be larger (4 bytes and an additional byte to indicate that the value is 4 bytes; a total of 5 bytes). In this case it will be more efficient to use a `fixed32`. We simply know a `fixed32` is 4 bytes; we don't need to serialize that `fixed32` is a 4-byte number.

And if we look at `fixed32` it actually mentions that the tradeoff point is around 2^28 (for unsigned integers).

So some types are good *[as in, more efficient in terms of storage space]* for large values, some for small values, some for positive/negative values. It all depends on what the actual values represent.

> "Are there any example scenarios?"

32-bit hashes (ie: CRC-32), IPv4 addresses/masks. A predictable message sizes could be relevant.

Comment: A good explanation, but then it seems to me the Protobuf has a really bad smell in data abstraction, as an IDL. That's too bad!